# Android RSA decryption returns 256 block

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, rsa

From code I have seen on the net I was under the impression that decrypting an RSA 256 byte block (2048 bit key) representing an encrypted String would produce just the bytes for the String. I don't get that on Android - I get a block of 256 bytes with the String followed by nulls (0). Is this correct behaviour?

My test code from my app as follows:

```
keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(publicModulus,
                    publicExponent);
key = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory
                    .generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] bytes = "hello".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);

pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(privateModulus,
                    privateExponent);
key = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory
                    .generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] utf8 = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
String plainString = new String(utf8, "ISO-8859-1");
```

utf8 is returned as a byte array of length 256. "hello" occupies the first 5 bytes, the rest are null, so my plainString is incorrect. If I specify the cypher instance as "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" then "hello" appears at the end of the 256 byte block preceded by nulls.

I see people directly converting the byte array to String as I've done and clearly they are getting the correct length string back. So what have I done wrong?

Comment: You should decrypt with an RSAPrivateKey, not an RSAPublicKey.

Comment: Hmm. You mean the cast, I take it.

Comment: Ok, that's got it. Thanks - problem with cutting and pasting code.

Comment: is there a reason you don't use a standard padding like OAEP?

Comment: I believe that "RSA" on its own uses whatever is the default. As this is different for Java (my server) and Android (my client), I have set them to RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding. I'm new to crypto, so all this is new territory for me. It all works very nicely now.